# ArcGIS Field Calculator: Conditional statement syntax error

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

Rudimentary Python/ArcPy skills at work here, not sure where I'm going wrong.

Trying to do a simple random selection of 10 features from a layer to be indicated by the placement of a "1" in another attribute set aside for this purpose.  Basic concept is is to use random.sample() to generate a random list of 10 FID's, and then check to see if each FID is in the list.  NewID is an attribute containing FID's values.  This is what I have in the code block:

```
import random
def randSelTen():
      featurecount = arcpy.GetCount_management("layer_name")
      linecount = int(str(featurecount))
      lst_oids = range(0, linecount)
      rand_lines = random.sample(lst_oids, 10)
      if !NewID! in rand_lines:
           return 1
      else:
           return 0
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the conditional containing !NewID!, and no matter what I do I can't fix it.  If I replace !NewID! with an integer, the script runs, but of course the output is bad.  Any help is appreciated... thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to search for a string `!NewID!` in `rand_lines` you have to format it as a string: `if '!NewID!' in rand_lines'`

Comment: Thank you... I'm trying use Field Calculator to count the features in a shp, build a string consisting of a random sample of 10 FID's, check to see if each FID is in the string, and populate another attribute with a 1 or 0 if the FID is in the sample string.

Comment: With your correction, the script runs, but my output is all zeros. I think the problem now is that a new set of 10 random features is being generated with each iteration of the field calculation, which is not what I want... I want to use the same list of 10 random features for each iteration, which should leave me with ten 1's. Maybe this is not possible with Field Calculator?  Thanks again!

Comment: Are you doing this in the Field Calculator tool in ArcMap or in a script using the arcpy.CalculateField_management() function? Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting this code in the "Codeblock" of the field calculator then the reason you are getting a syntax error is because you can not access fields like that from the codeblock. You must pass in the field as an argument to the function. So you would have to do this:

```
# -----Codeblock---------
import random
def randSelTen(NewID):
  featurecount = arcpy.GetCount_management("layer_name")
  linecount = int(str(featurecount))
  lst_oids = range(0, linecount)
  rand_lines = random.sample(lst_oids, 10)
  if NewID in rand_lines:
       return 1
  else:
       return 0

# ----- Expression (goes in bottom text box of the field calculator if using GUI) -----
randSelTen(!NewID!)
```